# Piping between two programs Delphi

Tags: delphi, pipe, piping

I want to make a program that will do piping between two programs

Getting input from first, giving it to second that will do processing on it and give it back to me which I will give back to first

```
  if Input <> '-' then
    InS := TFileStream.Create(Input, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite)
  else
    InS := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));

  if Output <> '-' then
    OutS := TFileStream.Create(Output, fmCreate or fmShareExclusive)
  else
    OutS := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));

  FillChar(StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo), 0);
  FillChar(ProcessInfo, sizeof(ProcessInfo), 0);

  SecurityAttributes.nLength := sizeof(SecurityAttributes);
  SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle := True;
  SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor := Nil;

  CreatePipe(OutPipe, InPipe, @SecurityAttributes, 0);

  StartupInfo.cb := sizeof(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  StartupInfo.hStdInput := InPipe;
  StartupInfo.hStdOutput := OutPipe;

  Handle := CreateProcess(PChar(CLSAppInfo.CLSExeName),
    PChar(Format('a - -', [])), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, PChar(GetCurrentDir),
    StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);

  if Handle then
  begin
    GetMem(Buffer, BLOCK_SIZE);
    repeat
      ReadByte := InS.Read(Buffer^, BLOCK_SIZE);
      isOK := WriteFile(InPipe, Buffer^, ReadByte, WroteByte, nil);

      WriteLn(ReadByte.ToString);
      WriteLn(isOK.ToString());

      if (not isOK) or (ReadByte = 0) then
        break;

      repeat
        isOK := ReadFile(OutPipe, Buffer^, 255, ReadByte, nil);
        if not isOK then
          break;
        if ReadByte = 0 then
          break;

        OutS.Write(Buffer, ReadByte);
      until 0 = 1;
    until 0 = 1;

    FreeMem(Buffer);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
  end;

  CloseHandle(InPipe);
  CloseHandle(OutPipe);

  OutS.Free;
  InS.Free;
```

But this just starts the programs and the programs ends without doing anything

Comment: Your pipe connects the stdout of the process to its own stdin. Anything that the program outputs is fed back in to its own input. You are just looking to read the stdout of this other process. Is that right? Create a pipe. Use the write end of the pipe as the stdout of the other process. Have your process read from the read end of the pipe.

Comment: I want to feed output of an exe to another exe waiting for input and feeds its output back to first exe as input, so I think a pipe here is needed

Comment: The code doesn't appear to do anything like that. You appear to be quite confused. I suggest that you start by simplifying. See if you can read the output of a program using a pipe. Once you can do that, work up to the more complex problem that is your ultimate goal. Don't make the mistake of starting with the complex problem and then when you get stuck having no idea what went wrong.

Comment: @MianBilawal yes, but you are not using the pipe *correctly*. You are assigning both ends of a single pipe to one spawned process. Like David said, anything the process outputs will loop back to itself. For what you are attempting, you need 2 pipes, one for stdin and another for stdout/err. Write to one pipe, read from the other. Not 1 pipe for both. [See MSDN's example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)